# How do you scrape tables on multiple webpage addresses using pandas & beautiful soup?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to pull data from a table on a website. The table exist across 165 webpages, and I would like to scrape it all. I have only been able to get the first page.

I have tried pandas, beautifulsoup, requests

```
offset = 0
teacher_list = []
while offset <= 4500:

calls_df, = 
pd.read_html("https://projects.newsday.com/databases/long- 
island/teacher-administrator-salaries-2017-2018/?offset=0" + 
str(offset), header=0, parse_dates=["Start date"])

    offset = offset + 1500
    print(calls_df)

    # calls_df = "https:" + calls_df
    collection_page = requests.get(calls_df)
    page_html = collection_page.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

    print(page_html)
    print(soup.prettify())


print(teacher_list)
offset = offset + 1500
print(teacher_list,calls_df.to_csv("calls.csv", index=False))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a step parameter to increment your url

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

with requests.Session() as s:
    for i in range(0, 246001, 1500):
        url = 'https://projects.newsday.com/databases/long-%20island/teacher-administrator-salaries-2017-2018/?offset={}'.format(i)
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        dfCurrent = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('html')))[0]
        dfCurrent.dropna(how='all', inplace = True)
        df = pd.concat([df, dfCurrent])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```